# Why isn't the object attribute available?

Tags: python

```
class Test:

    def __int__(self):
        self.name = 'test'

        print('Initialized ...')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test = Test()
    print(test.name)
```

When I run it, it gives this error message：

```
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `__init__` instead of `__int__`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

```
def __int__(self):
```

is misspelled - you don't see "Initialized ..." printed either, do you?

```
def __init__(self):
```

is the correct spelling.